# Java: Правильность проверки массива на !=null. Соответствие решения условиям задачи

Tags: java, null

Есть задача:

> Перейдите в класс SumOfEvenNumbers и реализуйте метод sum. Правильная
> реализация должна получить массив значений int и вернуть сумму четных
> чисел.
>
> Подробности:
>
> Если данный массив равен нулю или пуст, метод возвращает 0. Метод sum
> не должен изменять массив. Входной массив может содержать любое
> значение типа int от Integer.MIN_VALUE до Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Мое решение:

```
package com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays;



public class SumOfEvenNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 3, 2, 8, 15, 199};

        System.out.println(sum(array));
    }

    public static Long sum(int[] array) {

        long sum = 0;
        if (array.length != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i< array.length;i++) {
                if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && i !='\0') {
                    sum += array[i];
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Null");
        }
        return sum;

        //put your code here
    }
}
```

При прогоне тестов ошибка. Писал for (int i : array) -> array[i] менял на i. Не пониманию ошибку. Курс EPAM

### Ошибка
Test set: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests

```
Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 14, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.283 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests
com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[1]  Time elapsed: 0.084 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[2]  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[3]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[4]  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[5]  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[6]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[7]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[8]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[9]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[10]  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[11]  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[12]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(int, int[])[13]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)

com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.nullOrEmptyTest  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.nullOrEmptyTest(Tests.java:48)
```

Код Теста

```
package com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays;


public class Tests {

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "[{index}] [{0}]")
    @MethodSource("testCases")
    public void sumTest(int expected, int[] array) {
        assertEquals(expected, SumOfEvenNumbers.sum(array));
    }

    public static Stream<Arguments> testCases() {
        return Stream.of(
                arguments(10, new int[]{1, 3, 2, 8, 15, 199}),
                arguments(208, new int[]{1, 3, 2, 8, 198, 15}),
                arguments(0, IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(1000).toArray()),
                arguments(2000, IntStream.generate(() -> 2).limit(1000).toArray()),
                arguments(0, IntStream.generate(() -> 0).limit(1000).toArray()),
                arguments(250500, IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(1000).toArray()),
                arguments(4840, IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 3).limit(80).toArray()),
                arguments(1048574, IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + i).limit(20).toArray()),
                arguments(0, IntStream.iterate(1, i -> -i).limit(80).toArray()),
                arguments(-1560, IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i - 1).limit(80).toArray()),
                arguments(50, IntStream.iterate(50, i -> i - 1).limit(100).toArray()),
                arguments(-4900, IntStream.iterate(50, i -> i - 2).limit(100).toArray()),
                arguments(-4850, IntStream.iterate(50, i -> i - 3).limit(100).toArray())
        );
    }


    @Test
    public void nullOrEmptyTest() {
        int[] nullArray = null;
        int[] emptyArray = new int[0];

        assertEquals(0, SumOfEvenNumbers.sum(nullArray));
        assertEquals(0, SumOfEvenNumbers.sum(emptyArray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Итак, вся соль была в обработке исключения. После прохождения других курсов до меня дошло.

```
public class SumOfEvenNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 3, 2, 8, 15, 199};
        System.out.println(sum(array));
    }

    public static int sum(int[] array) {
        try {

            int x = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    x += array[i];
                }
            }
            return x;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: В _вашем_ коде НЕ будет выброшено исключение.  Чтобы избежать `NullPointerException` в тестах, достаточно было проверить входной аргумент на `null`, о чём вам писали в ответах ещё 20 сентября.  Хорошо, что хотя бы сигнатуру метода переписали корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте пожалуйста ошибку, потому что без нее не очень понятна проблема.
Предполагаю , что ошибка на этапе проверки решения. Есть определенная вероятность , что из-за того , что вы на выход печатаете "Null" (по условию задачи в этом нет необходимости)

Comment: Да нет. это я для себя написал.

Answer (score 0):

`i !='\0'` в данном случае лишь пропускает первый элемент массива, и в Java так не пишут, возможно это из Си. Вместо этого стоит добавить проверку на null в первый `if`:

```
if (array != null && array.length != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i< array.length;i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Null or empty");
}
```

Comment: Если честно не совсем понимаю принцип работы именно этой проверки. Нашел вариант на проверку  на null.

Comment: @yaVodyanoy Возможно, взято из Си, в Java так не нужно писать).

Comment: Вы правы, перепроверил. Больше не буду)

Comment: @yaVodyanoy Кстати, ответ обновлён. Так всё равно ошибки в тестах возникают?

Может проблемы со сборкой...

Comment: Доброго дня, пробовал и так, NoSuchMethod. По сборке вряд ли, это курс epam, давно бы уже были похожие отклики))

Comment: @yaVodyanoy, сборка зависит от сборщика. А тут похоже на проблему с импортом на этапе выполнения тестов.

Comment: @yaVodyanoy, пробовали на новом проекте создать этот класс и протестировать?

Answer (score 0):

А если отсечь всё лишнее?

```
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< array.length;i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
return sum;
```

Comment: Не проходит. пробовал

Answer (score 0):

***Обновление:*** Ошибка:

> `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.SumOfEvenNumbers.sum([I)I at com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays.Tests.sumTest(Tests.java:21)`

означает, что код в тестовом методе `sumTest` на 21 строке класса `Tests` пытается вызвать метод, который принимает на вход *массив целых чисел типа int* `[I`, и возвращает целое число типа `int`, на что указывает буква `I` после закрывающей скобки.

Вам нужно сравнить входной массив с `null`, иначе в строчке `if (array.length == 0)` будет выброшено знаменитое исключение `NullPointerException`.  Также необходимо изменить сигнатуру метода `sum`, чтобы она соответствовала ожидаемой, и не возникала ошибка теста:

```java
public static int sum(int ... arr) {
    int total = 0;
    if (null != arr) {
        for (int n : arr) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                total += n;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

В функциональном стиле с использованием `Optional` и Stream API:

```java
public static int sum(int ... arr) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(arr)
        .map(IntStream::of)        // IntStream
        .orElse(IntStream.empty()) // пустой стрим если входной массив null
        .filter(n -> (n & 1) == 0) // проверка на четность по младшему разряду
        .sum();                    // корректная сумма
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что по курсу совершенно не проходили вот это вот все. прошли циклы, дошли до массивов  и нужно выполнить практику на основе пройденного материала. Я просто не понимаю написанного с использованием Optional. однозначно буду читать, но мне кажется что я просто где то накосячил. И если не трудно может вы подробнее напишите про использование Optional именно здесь, только без написания правильного кода если можно, сам хочу дойти.

Comment: Второй вариант приведен просто как пример использования `Optional`.  "Косяк" с отсутствием проверки на null исправлен в первом примере кода.

Comment: @yaVodyanoy, я объяснил причину исключения `NoSuchMethodError` и исправил код.

Comment: Не пройдет "public static Long sum(int[] array)" с этого и пошел гуглить)))

Comment: Последний комментарий не понятен.  У вас есть доступ к коду теста?  Да, и представленное сообщение об ошибке никак не связано с проверкой на `null`, о которой был первоначальный вопрос

Comment: Добавил как код теста в основной запрос

Comment: Пробовали подставить какое-либо из предложенных решений вместо своего ошибочного кода?

Comment: Если б я еще видел решение в используемых тестах)) обязательно б попробовал. Буду думать, спасибо за время!

Comment: @yaVodyanoy, можете попробовать отредактировать свой класс `SumOfEvenNumbers`: 1) удалить свою ошибочную реализацию метода `sum` 2) скопировать и вставить в класс `SumOfEvenNumbers` первую _исправленную_ реализацию метода `sum` в [данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450361/386633). 3) запустить тест.

Comment: package com.epam.rd.autotasks.arrays;

public class SumOfEvenNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 3, 2, 8, 15, 199};

        System.out.println(sum(array));
    }

    public static int sum(int[] array){

        //put your code here

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}  Вот так выглядит первоначалка. int поменял на long видимо уже я, в процессе своих попыток, косяк, но код все равно не работает. Вы не могли бы объяснить как здесь отрабатывает throw в последней строке?

Comment: И если честно вообще не понял зачем копировать в  класс SumOfEvenNumbers Ваш код, ведь есть четкое указание места написания. Чувствую себя тупым, но самостоятельно не могу разобраться((

Comment: __int поменял на long__ - А зачем вы это сделали??  Тесты ожидают, что будет возвращаться результат именно типа 'int'.  Именно об этом говорит ошибка `NoSuchMethodError`, о чём  я тоже написал.